# Db2 connection problem with IBM DB2

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to connect a db2 database using php. Now, i am gonna write some code similar to this(call a stored procedure):

```
$proc = 'CALL MyLib.MySP(?, ?, ?)'; 
$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $proc) or die("db2_prepare failed<br>"); 

// Define input variable values // 
$paramIN1  = ...; 
$paramIN2  = ...; 
$paramOUT3 = ""; 

// Define parameters // 
db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, "paramIN1", DB2_PARAM_IN); 
db2_bind_param($stmt, 2, "paramIN2", DB2_PARAM_IN); 
db2_bind_param($stmt, 3, "paramOUT3", DB2_PARAM_OUT); 

// Display results set // 
if (db2_execute($stmt)) { 
    while ($row = db2_fetch_array($stmt)) { 
        print "  {$row[0]}, {$row[1]}, {$row[5]}<br>"; 
    } 
}
```

Connection code:

```
$user = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$hostname = 'ip';
$db = 'db';
$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};HOSTNAME=$hostname;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;DATABASE=$db;";

$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, $user, $password);
```

Connection fails here. Error message returned from db2_conn_errormsg() is:

```
"[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1032N No start database manager command was issued. SQLSTATE=57019 SQLCODE=-1032"
```

This is an AS/400 system. With odbc we can connect and talk to database without a problem.

Comment: That message indicates a failure to connect to the database server.  Are you using the CLI Driver with your other odbc connections or the iSeries Access driver?

Comment: [IBM][CLI Driver] is the DB2 ODBC driver not the iSeries Access driver.  Check your ODBC provider configuration.

Comment: Thanks, working on it but nothing so far.

Answer (score 0):

[IBM][CLI Driver] is the [DB2 ODBC](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418043) driver not the [iSeries Access ODBC](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Frzaikappodbc.htm) driver.  From what I can discern it also requires [DB2 Connect](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/db2connect/) to enable a connection to an AS/400 host.

A failure to connect using the iSeries Access ODBC driver results in the following message:

`[IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver]Communication link failure. comm rc=8015 - CWBSY1006 - User ID is invalid, Password length = 0, Prompt Mode = Never, System IP Address = 127.0.0.1`

Check the database driver on your ODBC DSN.

[image: ODBC Data Source Administrator]

Comment: Thank you for your helping. I guess you are right but still can't connect. I created  new dsns with DB2 ODBC Driver and also "IBM DATA Server Driver for ODBC" which came with DB2 Connect. Only difference is when i use "IBM DATA Server Driver for ODBC" this time i get " The database alias "" could not be found in the db2dsdriver.cfg configuration file" error message. I tried to define different aliases but that didn't work either. DB2 ODBC Driver returns the same error in the question.

Comment: In a previous comment you said you were using the iSeries Access ODBC driver however that's not the driver you are configuring in your DSN.  I believe you either need to switch to the iSeries Access ODBC driver or configure DB2 Connect so that you can use the DB2 ODBC Driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect with db2 using:

```
$dbh = db2_connect('*LOCAL', $user, $password, array("i5_lib"=> $db);
```

If the DB2 database and the ZendServer are in the same IBM i then '*LOCAL', else the DB2 name.

Comment: There isn't ZendServer on IBM i. Php code runs on a different machine.