# DB2 PHP Connection

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange

Been digging through stackoverflow for a few days now. Need to connect to a DB2 database with PHP. The following code doesn't return the error message or any helpful information, and instead just breaks Javascript later in the page.

```
include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/inc/library/adodb_lite/adodb.inc.php'); 
   $DBName = 'DBNAME';
   $Host = 'IPADDRESS';
   $User = 'USER';
   $Password = 'PASS';

   $db = ADONewConnection('db2');

   $dsn = "driver={IBM db2 odbc DRIVER};Database=$DBName;hostname=$Host;protocol=TCPIP;uid=$User;pwd=$Password";
     if ($db->Connect($dsn)) {
     echo "<div style='color:green;font-size:21px;'>Connection Successful.</div>";
             } else {
                 echo "<div style='color:#cc0000;font-size:21px;'>Connection Failed db->Connect(dsn)</div>";
                 echo 'SQLSTATE: '.$db->ErrorNo()."<br>";
                 echo 'Message: '.$db->ErrorMsg()."<br>";
             }
```

As followed by http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You may find solution in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980927/db2-connection-problem-with-ibm-db2?rq=1

Comment: Like I said I'd been all over stackoverflow, reading relevant tags. Unfortunately unlike in that thread, I'm not seeing any error messages or useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought is that your driver name doesn't match what you have in your odbcinst.ini file. Here's what I'm using:

odbcinst.ini

```
[iSeries Access ODBC Driver]
Description     = iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver          = /usr/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
NOTE1           = If using unixODBC 2.2.11 or later and you want the 32 and 64-bit ODBC drivers to share DSN's,
NOTE2           = the following Driver64/Setup64 keywords will provide that support.
Driver64        = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading       = 2
DontDLClose     = 1
UsageCount      = 1
```

Note that the "name" of this driver is defined to be "iSeries Access ODBC Driver" - whatever you put between the brackets [].

Now my PHP code looks like this:

```
$this->db_connection = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=$this->he_database_server;PROTOCOL=TCPIP", $temp_username, $temp_password);
```

So check to make sure your driver name (IBM db2 odbc DRIVER) is the same in your odbcinst.ini file.

Now if that doesn't solve the problem I would recommend you turn on ODBC logging by adding the following to your odbcinst.ini file:

```
[ODBC]
TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log
Trace = Yes
```

That will write out a lot of information to a log file and give you a good idea of what's wrong.  If that still doesn't get it working my only other suggestions are the most basic of things: make sure the username/password is correct, the AS/400 is reachable from the server running PHP, etc.

Comment: I was sure I had overlooked something important, like odbcinst.ini. I'm using adodb_lite, thought I installed the iSeries ODBC driver, but don't see odbcinst.ini (IBM/DB2 newb).

Comment: The odbcinst.ini file will be installed when you install odbc.

**`sudo apt-get install unixodbc php5-odbc`**

On Ubuntu it will put odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini in /etc. When I installed the iSeries driver I had to also do:

**`sudo cp /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib/* /usr/lib`**

to get the .so files in the place where ODBC expected them.

Have you tried going to a command line and using the isql command to see if you can connect to the AS/400?

Comment: Tried downloading the DB2 ODBC driver from IBM from https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=4020&uid=swg27016878 (per http://uzyn.com/how-to-connect-to-db2-on-php-via-odbc/), but once done and extracted there's no odbcinst.ini. Am I downloading the wrong package?

Comment: I downloaded the driver from http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/linux_resources.html (You will need to have an account on their site to download the driver).

It's an RPM so I used "alien" to convert it to a DEB package for Ubuntu: **sudo alien iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.2.i386.rpm**

However to answer your question - the odbc.ini and ocbcinst.ini files will be installed when you install unixodbc (and you'll also need the php5-odbc package on Ubuntu so PHP can use ODBC).

Comment: Thanks for your help Benny. The site and connecting DB2 are on Windows servers with PHP 5.3.8. Is there something comparable to unixodbc I can use?

Comment: Ah, that could make a difference. I'm definitely not a Windows guy but Google tells me you can set up DSN's (Data Source Names) by going to: Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC). I'm assuming at that point you'll be able to specify all the things I put in an odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files. Please note that the Windows iSeries driver might be called something entirely different than what I mentioned above. Maybe this page will be useful: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216428

Answer (score 2):

try using this

http://www.sitepoint.com/php-database-db2/

Comment: Good info, but didn't quite help my scenario. Thanks though Dilip!